# VBAのセルのrange("")の式展開について

Tags: vba

vbaでrangeの式展開は可能なのでしょうか？stringはどうやらできるみたいなのですが、rangeは可能なのでしょうか。一応やりたいことは下記のようなコードです。

#### 特定のセルだけに色を付ける => cells()を使って書いたもの

```
'このコードは成功しました
sub cellcolor
for i = 3 to 27 step 4
 for j = 1 to 13
  cells(i, j).interior.colorindex = 3
  cells(i + 1, j).interior.colorindex = 4
  cells(i + 2, j).interior.colorindex = 5
next j: next i
end sub
```

#### rangeで式展開しようと試みたができなかったコード

```
sub sippai
set r as range = range.format("a{i}", "m{i}")
for i = 3 to 27 step 4
    r.interior.colorindex = 3
next i
End sub
```

Comment: 質問者さんは半年くらいここを訪れていないようですが、この記事を参考に(結局はcell位置に変換して計算かもしれませんが)応用出来るでしょう。[【ExcelVBA】RangeとCellsの座標を相互に変換する方法](https://website-note.net/vba/change-range-to-cells/)

Answer (score 1):

#### 行を選択する rows()がある。

```
sub step_row
for i = 3 to 27 step 4
  rows(i).interior.colorindex = 3
next i
end sub
```

しかし、行全体が選択されてしまい、止めたいところで止めれないという問題あり。